# Tkinter - Inserting text into canvas windows

Tags: python, text, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tkinter canvas populated with text and canvas windows, or widgets, created using the `create_text` and `create_window` methods. The widgets I place on the canvas are text widgets, and I want to insert text into them after they are created and placed. I can't figure out how to do this, if it's even possible. I realise you can edit them after creation using `canvas.itemconfig(tagOrId, cnf)`, but text can't be inserted that way. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, lets get the terminology straight: you aren't creating widgets, you're creating canvas items. There's a big difference between a Tkinter text widget and a canvas text item.

There are two ways to set the text of a canvas text item. You can use [itemconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) to set the `text` attribute, and you can use the [insert](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.insert-method) method of the canvas to insert text in the text item.

In the following example, the text item will show the string "this is the new text":

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=500)
        canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        canvas_id = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw")

        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="this is the text")
        canvas.insert(canvas_id, 12, "new ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```